# Функции для работы с консолью linux

Tags: c, консоль, linux

Помогите реализовать следующий хидер (под linux на Си) для управления консолью.

console.h:

```
typedef struct tagConsole
{
  int w, h, color, bgcolor, x, y, cursortype;
} console_t;

extern console_t console;

int getch(void);
void initConsole(void);
void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void clear(void);
void setcursortype(int t);
void settextcolor(int c);
void setbgcolor(int c);
void putchxy(char ch, int x, int y);
void putchxyc(char ch, int x, int y, int c);
void putchc(char ch, int c);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В юниксах отображение текста и вообще состояние терминала осуществляется с помощью управляющих последовательностей символов. Погуглите, отыщете описания.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону curses.